# What would be a good reason for a group of advanced soldiers not to clear a building from the top down?

Tags: military

So I'm working on a sci-fi novel, and there's one scene I'm having a little trouble backing up. In this scene, a squad of 5 soldiers are infiltrating an enemy base from the bottom up in order to take over a rebel command center on one of the upper floors. I read somewhere online that the easiest way to sweep a building is from the top down, but I wanted to add in an element of difficulty by going from the bottom up.

The squad's near-future weapons are slightly more advanced than the rebels, but not so much that they could just mow their way through the crowd of enemies like it was nothing. It's not a crash landing or survival scenario; it's a planned raid on the base.

So, what would be a realistic scenario that would make a top entry impossible and a bottom entry the only doable option?

Comment: Perhaps the only way into the building is through the bottom? (i.e.the building has no interior access to the roof, no way for the squad to get on the roof to begin with other than through the inside of the building, or nothing resembling a traditional roof -- something like the [Transamerica Pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transamerica_Pyramid) would very much not lend itself to a top-down clearance strategy, simply as a function of the architecture of the building not allowing any entry points at the top)

Comment: Top down is preferred, but given the difficulty of doing so, modern armies have drills for assaulting buildings from virtually any aspect.

Comment: yeah top down has some advantages, but it rarely the way it gets done, getting to the top is just too much trouble, plus it is much harder for your team too pull out if things go bad.

Comment: Isn't the obvious danger that the guys in the building have mined it? When the situation is hopeless they bring the building down on the invaders (suicide if they cannot run, but such action is not uncommon)

Comment: Is approaching underground (sewers) a valid reason? If the building is heavily defended, approaching underground then "opening" a hole in the basement would allow getting in close contact without having to face heavy armament.

Comment: I think this is probably off-topic, since it focuses on the actions of a small group of people in a manner that is not applicable in a larger sense.

Comment: The owners of this base also thought that going through the roof is the best idea, thus invested in superior anti air guns? Thus going from bottom actually brings some element of surprise?

Answer (score 7):

While several other answers suggest "why" the team approaches from the ground, we can simply stipulate that coming in at ground level is the easiest means of doing so (no helicopters or HAHO parachute drops are available, for example). This does not mean that you have covered all the bases yet, since assaulting buildings is a highly developed drill.

Firstly, the  building needs to be isolated. Ideally, you have enough troops and firepower to create an inner and outer cordon, with the inner cordon focused on preventing escape from the building, while the outer cordon prevents reinforcements from entering the fight. If you do not have enough troops to do both, then as a minimum you need do decide where the greater threat is and arrange your cordon accordingly. The absolute minimum wold be a machine gun posted to cover the front and side, and a second machine gun to cover the rear and other side (both guns placed so their arcs of fire don't cover the other gun).

Inside the building, you need to compartmentalize and isolate sections of the building and then ensure you yourself are not going to be trapped inside. Rooms and hallways are always secured by posting soldiers in areas you have cleared of the enemy, and many of the solders have secondary duties as "linkmen" to provide communications, direction and guidance to forces entering or exiting the building, to ensure rapid and smooth movement, no bunching up and no congestion in the hallways, for example. The linkmen can also serve to visually identify where the assaulting party is by hanging markers out of windows, for example.

Since you have a "movie" scenario where a five man team is assaulting the building, but you actually need a platoon or even a company of troops to do so, there is a problem.

However, since this is the "near future", you also have a solution: Robots!. The team might actually arrive riding on a pair of fire support robots (another good reason to come in by ground; the lift vehicles to carry the robots and the team would be large and conspicuous). The robots drop off the troops and move into support positions to isolate the building, and should have enough firepower to deal with shooting through the building itself and at least enemy LAV's. Dealing with tanks and IFV's or other heavy vehicles might require more or more specialized robots. You might have to arrive with a convoy.

[image]

*Prototype fire support robot*

[image]

*Prototype transport robot. This size robot could carry some heavy weapons in a fire support role*

Inside the building, small robots can be deployed to scout ahead, serve as sentries at important junctions, and (depending on the technology) possibly as local fire support to secure areas. As a very minimum, they need to be able to communicate to the team and the fire support robots to warn of movement and call fire (a 40mm grenade launcher or .50 HMG shooting through the walls will deter a lot of enemy activity). Some of these robots are small enough to be carried in a backpack and tough enough to be thrown through a window or down a flight of stairs.

[image]

*Small military robot by iRobot*

So your five man team can take a ground approach, especially if the robots are large enough to be used as ground transport, and use robotic augmentation to turn what looks like a suicide mission into a very doable one.

Answer (score 3):

## The base is a tower with dudes carrying RPGs on the roof

Or they could have SA-7s or Stingers or some man-portable anti-aircraft weapon. I wouldn't want to go to the top of that tower, not in a helicopter, parachute, or otherwise.

Taking a cue from movies, this situation could be like *The Rock*. The enemy base is a fortress that is well guarded by Marines with heavy weapons and missiles. Air and surface approach is not feasible, so the only way in is through the sewers.

Answer (score 2):

## roof intrusion

While the easiest way to clear a building is top-to-ground, it relies on several points to clear out the whole building and disallow escapees:

- means to take out any roof defenders in time
- availability of a higher position (higher roof, helicopter, plane) to get over the other building
- means of relative safe infiltration (ropes, parachute)
- backup to cover the entrances/exits of the building at ground level to prevent escapees running down and out

Now, what happens if one of the spots is not given?

If the roof defenders can't be taken out of the picture due to some reason, then insertion over the roof might not be safe - the whole approach might be impossible because they have some means to shoot down the transport.
But even if the roof can be cleared, not having some means of transport available makes roof intrusion impossible: maybe other positions prevent airdrop, maybe it is the tallest building around, in the end: no access to the roof means having to fight upwards.
But even if you might have a transport you might not be able to use it because you can't guarantee a safe and fast intrusion. There might not be a possible landing spot, there are no parachutes available due to shortage or the transport vehicle that is available can neither land on the roof nor is it equipped with ropes to slide down from.
Last but not least, there might not be enough manpower to encircle the building fully, thus making an assault from the roof a moot thing as the enemy can just retreat downwards and out of the building, possibly even leaving the inserting forces trapped with a bomb.

## ground assault

Now, we have situations when roof insertion is not a viable option, is ground attack and fighting upwards a solution to all of them? The answer is "partly", as I will explain. So let's see what factors are needed for a ground assault.

- some means of cover to get to the building with little casualties
- backup to cover other entrances to prevent escapees

As you see easily, we need to get to the building, and we don't want to loose our precious people in storming against a fortified position. Because of this, we need some kind of cover to get there. Modern troops usually rely on armored vehicles, allowing the group to advance with some backup and possibly only disembark right in front of the entry. Other methods might be to assault through a neighboring building or to go through the sewers, if available.

## combined tactics

Mind you, the usual method SWAT and special forces employ when assaulting a building in a hostage situation is combining ground and roof access and working both up and down at the same time, forcing the defenders into a two-front situation.

Regular infantry though usually has only the ground option and then resorts to the third option in the shape of a siege: instead of outright assaulting the fortified position, they entrench and surround it. Then they wait for heavy reinforcement (tanks, armored transports) to either take out the building in a whole or cover their advance.

## application on case

Now, we have a movie situation that leaves us with 5 actors to actually clear the building. We need to check a few things before we can proceed if assaulting with only 5 is viable at all.

- Do they have some sort of backup to cover the exits?

This is essential because you don't want escapees. The backup can be quite nondescript: having a police force that cordons off the area or a few military drones that do the job is just as viable as having the driver/gunner of the transport that brought them to the entry do the job. Note that a ground-bound vehicle might not be as fast as flying one but it can carry much heavier gear and armor than a same sized aircraft, as it doesn't need to reserve nearly as much power to actually staying aloft - weight simply doesn't matter that much on the ground.

So at least give them two vehicles backup to cover the building all around, possibly add a small dedicated group to keep the surroundings clear.

Answer (score 1):

Objective is important. They are infiltrating, there is no need to clear the building. Why is simple, as it is actually really hard to get yourself top of the building unnoticed and alive.

They can use a disguise to get close of the building, but there is a certain point which after they will notice the fraud and the combat begins; next to building they are required to identify themselves. There will be some confusion among the enemy at the beginning and that can be used for a rush to enemy command center. They will use stairway which has a door in every floor. The amount of enemies is manageable for 5 soldiers. Destroy the command center and the enemy is in even worse disarray. That can be enough to get out of the building, by for example out of the window with a rope, or using the different stairway as the enemy has stormed the one that was used, or some stayed at the stairway and defended it and they make a push back to the base floor and out of the base.

There is so many possible scenarios, but that's one.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's look at your situation and why attacking from the roof is preferable.**

When you attack an enemy CP using small unit SOF like that, you usually have more objectives than to destroy it. Often, you raid it to recover intelligence and/or kill or capture high value personnel. This is especially important because the enemy *will* react and send their QRF in to contain and kill the SOF team doing it, prevent their people being taken, their intelligence being recovered, or at the very least destroy both to prevent you from getting it.

When the CP is on top of a building like that, its often best to assault it directly by landing on the roof either from a helicopter, or - in case of your sci-fi scenario - landing from whatever means of insertion/transport you have available (drop pods, highly precise parachute drop, what have you.) This limits the time the personnel manning the post from enacting their burn order (destroying all intelligence), and evacuating their high-value people *downward* into *more* defenders.

This is especially true if, as you said, the building is an enemy base. Your SOF team may be able to deploy enough tech to defend the limited approaches from below long enough to raid the CP, collect what you need, and extract. But not indefinitely against enemies with vastly superior numbers and the enemy QRF coming in.

**Having said that, let's examine a few possibilities why you prefer to sneak up from the ground**

1. Heavy Air Defense. The enemy CP might be located deep inside a denied area covered by a competent, interconnected, networked Anti-Access/Area Denial system. The A2/AD will detect and defeat any attempt of approaching the building from above or even from orbit, forcing your team to land 'off-the-x' and patrol/infiltrate in on foot/local vehicles.
2. The location of the headquarters is unknown through your stand-off reconnaissance efforts. As in your SIGINT, ELINT, IMINT and other non-HUMINT assets failed to identify the building in question, and you have very limited HUMINT assets who, for some reason, cannot communicate the building's location to you, or you find it necessary for them to guide your team to the building. This forces you to infiltrate your team low profile, say into the enemy city, clandestinely make contact with your agents, and infiltrate/patrol in on foot.
3. You want to keep your raid a secret as long as possible. A team landing on the roof of your building, blowing the hinges off the CP's door, storming in and killing everyone tend to be noticed, no matter how fast they can do it. If you have a reason to want to keep your raid a secret as long as possible, you'd be forced to have your team infiltrate the base wearing enemy uniforms, and then work their way up clandestinely to the CP, until they can quietly secure it, recover what you need, then, as clandestinely, extract themselves.
4. He's not actually your enemy...yet. Sure you and him have signed a [Non-Aggression Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact), but your intel people, your agents, and your guts are telling you that he's about to launch a massive invasion across your border. *But* you don't want them to actually have *your* actions as the justification of their invasion, so you send your team in quietly, clandestinely, into teir city, make their way up into the CP, quietly (and deniably) eliminate everyone there (with gas, foreign weapons, etc), recover the invasion plans, and quietly make themselves out.

Of course there are complications and risks in each of these scenarios, but I think those should explain why your 5 man team need to do it from the ground up.

Comment: add notes about what the shorts mean: we are not all military people, and CP, QRF, SOF as way as the different INTs are spanish to me.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. Here it is:
CP = Command Post
QRF= Quick Reaction Force. This is a force set aside to be quickly deployed in support of certain situations and/or facilities.
SOF= Special Operations Forces
SIGINT/ELINT/IMINT/HUMINT= Signals Intelligence, Electronic Intelligence, Imagery Intelligence, Human Intelligence. Basically all the different sources of information.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

what if it's upside down?  (substitute lowest basement for top floor)

I mean, suppose the building is all underground.

The invasion will be top-down, but it will start from the ground floor.

Comment: Friend Jasen, can you run that by me again? More information and reasons for this inversion would improve this answer.

Comment: I get what he is saying. The reason for preferring a "top down" approach is because presumably enemy reinforcements can't come in behind you. So if the building is underground and the good guys start from the deepest layer (presumably getting access to it via some advanced tech the bad guys don't have), assaulting UP, that basically replicates assaulting a regular building from the top down.

Answer (score 0):

Identify a blatant weakness at ground level. For example, sewers with large accesses, leading straight to the main staircase - or side-entrances which, after enough observation, are never guarded.

It could also be an organisational weakness, like a botched shift. If the guards change at 3 am, and you identify one guy who is always leaving his guard too early / arriving two late, he's your entry point.